# PL/SQL: Using a variable in UPDATEXML function

Tags: sql, plsql, updatexml

I need to update an XML node that contains a specific number. My query works if I hard code in the number (see figure 1), but I would like to make this dynamic by passing through a variable that contains a string (variableToBeReplaced). I currently wrote this (see figure 2) but it isn't reading the variable correctly so no changes are being made to the xml. Does anyone know how I can include a variable in an updatexml() function?

Figure 1

```
select updateXML(xmltype(xmlbod),'/LpnList/Lpn/LicensePlateNumber[text() = "12345"]','67890').getClobVal() doc
from myTable
where id = '1'
```

Figure 2

```
select updateXML(xmltype(xmlbod), '/LpnList/Lpn/LicensePlateNumber[text()= '|| variableToBeReplaced || ']','67890').getClobVal() doc
from myTable
where id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing "" around the variable.

```
select updateXML(xmltype(xmlbod), '/LpnList/Lpn/LicensePlateNumber[text()= "'|| variableToBeReplaced || '"]','67890').getClobVal() doc
from myTable
where id = '1'
```